# Fluent NHibernate Error Mapping Assembly Outside of \bin (ASP.NET)

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, mapping, assemblies

I am trying to dynamically map one or more assemblies, that are themselves dynamically loaded into an ASP.NET website. I have my web.config setup to allow probing into a subdirectory called "paks" (which is also setup as an appSetting so I can build my path later to get to the DLLs) and this works 100% fine to load the main assemblies, but FluentNHibernate is having issues:

My .Mapping looks like this:

```
 .Mappings(m => {
   foreach (String assembly in assemblies) {
     String path = String.Format("{0}{1}\\{2}.dll", HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Packages"], assembly);
     AssemblyName y = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path);
     Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(y);
     m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(asm);
   }
 })
```

when I run it however I get an exception from :

"Could not compile the mapping document: (XmlDocument)"

but if I copy a second set of the DLLs into the \bin directory, magically things begin to work. I'm assuming because now NHibernate can locate the DLLs, whereas previous it couldn't. I don't have any issues loading them dynamically into .NET using Assembly.Load() so why is NHibernate having issues after they've been loaded?

Anyone have a clue as to how I can remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this, turns out these was a slight misunderstanding on my part about ASP.NET probing and assembly loading.
I thought that once an assembly was loaded it would be able to be located by objects that referenced it. But it seems that is not the case. To make matters worse, I thought probing would recursively traverse down into sub-directories (which it apparently does not) and was required for the initial loading I was doing (which is also not the case). My assembly resided in %root%/pak/pdf but my probe was only set for %root%/pak which is why, even though it was loaded, it could not be found by the other assemblies that referenced it.